# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1202,1) (301,5)

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, training-data, valueerror

```
def train( x_data_train, y_data_train, l_rate, iterations):

    w = np.zeros((x_data_train.shape[1], 1), dtype='f')
    b = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        y_pred = np.dot(x_data_train, w) + b
        delta = y_pred - y_data_train
        cost = np.sum(np.power((y_pred - y_data_train), 2))
        cost /= len(y_data_train)*2
        dw = np.dot(np.transpose(x_data_train), delta)
        dw = ((dw * l_rate) / len(x_data_train))
        db = np.sum(delta) * l_rate/len(x_data_train)
        w = w - dw
        b = b- db
        if (i%1000 == 0 or i == iterations -1):
            print("Iteration = ", i, "cost = ", cost)
    return w, b
```

This is my code and i am getting error at **delta = y_pred - y_data_train**

Comment: Why do you expect to subtract these 2 array?  You've given the function where the error occurs, but the problem is outside this function, in the choice or construction of the 2 array arguments.  What don't you understand about this error?